# add new input field like category?

Tags: categories, input

I want to create another input field like the categories. Whenever user posts 
a new question I want to have another drop down of locations associated with that particular
question, like categories drop down in the the 'Submit Question' form. And how I can add a UI for managing it in the admin section like the one there exists for categories in Questions?

Comment: Do you mean a plugin like this one: [Taxonomy Location](https://github.com/toscho/t5-taxonomy-location)?

Comment: I just want that when user post question, he must insert location that will be selected from drop down. and it will be managed from UI, exactly like Categories?

Comment: That plugin does not force a selection, but everything else is like categories.

Comment: thanks.. I've downloaded it, can you give me a link of how can I use it in my blog? It the read me file there is written, it will work when it will be activated.

Comment: `echo get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'location' ) );` will list the locations for a post in your theme.

Comment: @toscho thanks for your help. I've installed the plugin, it shows location option with posts, I want to attach it with questions, that is it should show an option on the 'submit questions page as it shows for new posts. How can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add extra fields to a post in the admin area, use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin. It is pretty good and has a lot of options.